# JmDNS create() function not working on my device

Tags: java, network-programming, mdns, jmdns

I am getting a strange error when trying to use JmDNS and I have no idea what's causing it. If, for example, I copy-paste the example program seen on the [JmDNS readme file](https://github.com/jmdns/jmdns) into Eclipse and run it, the line "JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost());" throws an error. The output tells me "Invalid argument: no further information", and I cannot find anything about what this entails.

In addition, the program I have created using JmDNS works perfectly fine when my classmate runs it, so it appears to be a problem specific to my device. Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Things I have tried:

- Using different inputs for create()
- Ensuring that IPv6 is enabled
- Ensuring that Java, JmDNS, and the compiler have permission to communicate over the private and public network
- Verifying that InetAddress.getLocalHost() returns a valid address

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I haven't used Java in nearly four years and am just now getting back into it.